# Determine if Windows 8 tablet is docked

Tags: vb.net, windows-8

How can I determine if a Windows 8 tablet PC is in a docking station?

Comment: It is typically good to *ask a question* here on Stack-o.

Answer (score 1):

The [ASHWID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.hardwareidentification.getpackagespecifictoken.aspx) contains a byte that indicates the docking station (when it is in a docking station).  [See this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431.aspx).  There is an example of an ASHWID with a docking station in the "Structure of an ASHWID" section.  (Given that, you should probably not try and do this as developing different behavior for different hardware specifics can be a bad idea).